# Generate interesting view of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table where there is a record for each week activities of my resources as follows;

```
Asset Name | Project | Week Beginning | Monday | Tuesday| Wednesday| Thursday| Friday| Saturday | Sunday

James   Project 1   26-06-2014  0   1   1   0   1   0   0
James   Project 1   03-07-2014  1   1   0   1   0   0   0
Dave    Project 3   03-07-2014  1   1   0   1   0   0   0
```

I need to see James and when he started and finished his project .

So I need a view like below

```
Asset Name | Project | Start Date on Project | End Date on Project| Number of days worked 
James       Project 1   27-06-2014  06-07-2014      6
Dave        Project 3   03-07-2014  06-07-2-14      3
```

So I was thinking of a case statement, cursor or a stored procedure with set based logic. I would like to work out the best and
fastest way of doing this . So any ideas how to generate this view quickly ? Brain freeze this morning due to a late one last night so if anyone can get me inspired I would most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT ASSETNAME,PROJECT,MIN(T.MIN)START_DAY,MAX(T.MAX) END_DAY,
       DATEDIFF(DD,MIN(t.min) ,MAX(T.MAX)) DURATION
FROM
(
SELECT  ASSETNAME,PROJECT,DATEADD(DD,MIN(WEEK),WEEKBEGINNING) 'MIN',DATEADD(DD,MAX(WEEK),WEEKBEGINNING) 'MAX'
FROM #TEMP  T
CROSS APPLY(SELECT 0 'WEEK' WHERE T.MONDAY=1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 WHERE T.TUESDAY=1 UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 WHERE T.WEDNESDAY=1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 WHERE T.THURSDAY=1 UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 WHERE T.FRIDAY=1 UNION ALL SELECT 5 WHERE T.SATURDAY=1 UNION ALL
            SELECT 6 WHERE T.SUNDAY=1 
            ) D
GROUP BY ASSETNAME,PROJECT,WEEKBEGINNING
)T
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, normalize your data, using `unpivot`, and convert the days to an actual date.

```
select AssetName, Project,
 dateadd(d, CASE dayname                    
                    WHEN 'Monday' THEN 0
                    WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 3
                    WHEN 'Friday' THEN 4
                    WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 5
                    When 'sunday' then 6
end,WeekBeginning) workdate
from
(                    
    select * from yourdata
    unpivot (dayvalue for dayname in (monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday)) u
) v
```

From there, it is a simple case of finding the earliest and latest records.

Comment: Thanks as this is a Massive help as a starting point for me.
Some feedback for anyone else using this query.
Performance - 2 mins to execute 
Data issues - Generates 2 records for a Monday and for a week where you work on 2 days, it comes up with 8 records.

Comment: @JamesKhan re: 2 records for Monday - a typo - edited. You can filter out the non-worked days with a simple where clause after the unpivot.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  assetName, project,
        MIN(DATEADD(d, first, weekBeginning)) AS startDate,
        MAX(DATEADD(d, last, weekBeginning)) AS endDate,
        SUM(days) AS daysWorked
FROM    mytable
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  SUM(d), MIN(n), MAX(n)
        FROM    (
                SELECT  monday, 0
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  tuesday, 1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  wednesday, 2
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  thursday, 3
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  friday, 4
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  saturday, 5
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  sunday, 6
                ) w (d, n)
        ) q (days, first, last)
GROUP BY
        assetName, project
```

Comment: Thanks outstanding. Massive help as a starting point.
Some feedback for anyone else using this query.
31 seconds to execute .
Syntax adjusted slightly by adding to the group by missing q.days,q.first,q.last. 
The end date does not work out correctly for scenario where people have worked less than 5 days in the week. Workaround was to used days worked to work out end date . The winner I think only just . Will tell u in 40 mins.

Comment: @JamesKhan: you don't need to add days etc to the group by. See the updated query.

Comment: Thanks for that. The end date is incorrect, it seems to be the same month as the start date . For example the end date should be 18/12/2013 but comes up as the 18/11/2013.

Comment: @JamesKhan: could you please post some sample data (which includes the dates you deem incorrect)?